# Python 2.7.10 ValueError: Incomplete Format if statement

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

```
def func():
import csv
file=open("cmiday.csv")
x,y=[],[]
reader=csv.DictReader(file)
for row in reader:
    if(type(row["max_rel_hum"])%1==0):
        continue
    if(type(row["precip"])%1==0):
        continue
    if(row["max_rel_hum"]>100):
        continue
    if(row["max_rel_hum"]<0):
        continue
    if (row["precip"]>10):
        continue
    if(row["precip"]<0):
        continue
    x.append(row["max_rel_hum"])
    y.append(row["precip"])
print x
print y
```

I'm trying to collect data from a csv file into lists x and y. I don't want any values for row["max_rel_hum"] to be integers or be more than 100 or less than 0. Similarly, I don't want any values for row["precip"] to be more than 10 or less than 0. I'm getting this error when I try to run the function:

```
>>> func()
Traceback (most recent call las
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <m
  File "hw.py", line 7, in func
    if(row["max_rel_hum"]%1==0)
ValueError: incomplete format
```

Please help out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Values from a CSV are strings, not integers. You're expecting `%` to do modulo, but on a string it does string formatting.

You need something like this:

```
if ( int(row["max_rel_hum"]) % 1 == 0):
```

And you need to do `int()` for in all the lines, even the `<` and `>` ones - they are valid operations on strings, but will do an alphabetical order comparison, not a numeric comparison, and won't give the results you expect.

You don't need `type()` in the `if` line at all.

Comment: So I tried what you did and it returned this error >>> func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "hw.py", line 11, in func
    if int(row["max_rel_hum"])%1==0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '95.9'

Comment: Oh, I missed the bit where you said "I don't want them to be integers", and I assumed that since you were doing modulo, you must want them to be integers. Try `float()` instead of `int()` - (although I'm not  sure whether floating point rounding errors will show up in this kind of usage).